# Convert data from XMLHttpRequest to array

Tags: javascript

How can I convert data from XHR to array?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        localStorage.setItem("index", JSON.stringify(this.responseText));
        indexArray = localStorage.getItem("index");
        console.log(typeof indexArray); // returns string, this should be array.
        console.log(indexArray[2]); // must return {10000003: 'How and Why.'}
        console.log(indexArray[2][10000003]); // must return How and Why.
    }
};
xhr.open("GET", "/list?i=" + input.value, true);
xhr.send();
```

data from `/list?i=hello` in a type of string

```
[{10000001: 'How are you?'}, {10000002: 'Hows your life'}, {10000003: 'How and Why.'}]
```

Comment: post what is your expected output?

Comment: localStorage holds a string. You can see that you are stringifying it when you set it. SO you need to parse it back into an array with JSON.parse() when you read it....

Comment: @epascarello However, if I do `localStorage.setItem("index", JSON.parse(this.responseText));` I will get an error.

Comment: @Andreas `Must return` instead of returns, my fault.

Comment: You need to store it as a sting and when you pull it out, you need to parse it....

Comment: You should use parse method to convert your data type from json. `console.log(typeof JSON.parse(indexArray))`

Comment: Everything's fine now. I just added tojson in my Jinja2 template `{{item|tojson}}`. Fault is in the Python code.